# Do INT score increases from items increase ranks you can spend on skills in Starfinder?

Tags: starfinder

Let's say my character has Mk1 Synaptic Accelerators that increase his INT by two (or his modifier by +1).

Does that retroactively give me more ranks to spend on skills?

I know this is the case with regular ability score increases. I was just curious if it applied to equipped items (which I imagine it does because equipment lasts longer than 24 hours).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes, it does

If you check personal upgrades (pg 212):

> Personal upgrades may be cybernetics, biotech upgrades, mystical crystals, nanite enhancements, or various other forms of enhancement, and each **permanently grants you additional ability score points**. Using any of these sorts of items counts as a personal upgrade.

If we compare this to what we are told earlier in the book, on the *Leveling* chapter (pg 26):

> If an ability score increase results in a change to an ability modifier, don't forget to adjust any statistics that rely on that modifier, such as attack bonuses, saving throws, total skill bonuses, Resolve Points, Stamina Points, and the DCs of class features and spells. Note that ability score increases are effective retroactively; when your character's ability score increases, it increases his total number of ability-based statistics -things like Resolve Points, Stamina Points, or **skill ranks**- as if he had the higher value at previous levels as well.

So, the only exception about personal upgrades seems to be when comparing your current ability score to 17+ to decide if it will increase by +1 or +2 when applying the ability increase gained every 5 levels.

> Each time he reaches one of these level thresholds (5th, 10th, 15th, and 20th-see Table 2-4). choose four of his ability scores to increase. If a chosen score is 17 or higher (excluding ability increases from **personal upgrades**-see page 212), it increases permanently by 1. If it's 16 or lower, it increases by 2.